# Is it theoretically possible to make an anti-jammer for WiFi?

Tags: rf, wifi

From the little I understand of WiFi jamming, it uses strong counterfeit signals that overwhelm legitimate signals.
I thought perhaps a device that emitted the same frequency but offset so that it cancels the jammer out might be able to negate the negative effect to some extent.
Would this idea work?

Comment: Perhaps a jammer locator along with a big honking laser or EMP gun?

Comment: Wonder why the close votes…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot jam a jammer away. For two signals to cancel, they need to be perfectly 180° out of phase. But the phase changes with distance from both transmitters - so the only possible scenario where that would work would be if both jammer and jammer-jammer would lie on a straight line with the receiver in the same line. And there must be no reflections of the transmission on anything around these things!

Since you can neither guarantee the receiver to hold perfectly still and stay on the exact same line going through jammer and your anti-jamming device that can't work. Furthermore, WiFi never takes place in outer space but practically always in multipath channel scenarios, there's always going to be multiple ways in which the jamming signal reaches the receiver, so it's impossible through that, as well.

Then, the usual jammer for wideband communication systems will not be a nice predictable waveform that you could just somehow generate the "opposite" of. It will be perfectly random noise - and no anti-jamming device could cancel that out, because you can't invert what you don't know.

You need to learn a bit more about fundamentals of RF propagation and about channel modeling, as well as probability theory for understanding random signals and random channels if you're into making receivers less susceptible to interference. It's an interesting aspect of most communication system designs, but the way you ask betrays that you're still at the very beginning of understanding it, maybe haven't yet had a lecture on the basics of communications engineering; since the people designing these systems all have learned all the basic stuff, you still have little chance of understanding what they do if you don't have a relatively broad basis in communications engineering. Luckily, that's part of the modern EE curriculum in most universities!

Comment: is there a bibliography would you recommend to learn about RF propagation and channel modeling as well as communications engineering? thank you

Comment: I really like this answer, except it'd be really helpful if you or someone else could add a bit more detail about how to obtain a "relatively broad basis in communications engineering" even if one isn't currently studying a "modern EE curriculum." Do you have any recommendations for textbooks or other materials?

Comment: uff, yes, I do, but sadly, they would amount to the higher math courses I, II and III for EE, a primer on probability theory with focus on stochastic processes (which is about the focus of the exercises I held for that subject), a textbook in a semester course titled "Signals and Systems" and a textbook for "Communications Engineering", which will require these math basics… in other words, I think the easiest way to get there is pretty much studying the first two years of math from an EE program, and then set a bit of stochastic signals theory and comms engineering on top.

Comment: Not knowing which math background you bring, I'd say: Make sure you know what a derivative of a complex-valued function is, and that you can work with \$s(t) = e^{j 2\pi f t}\$ reasonably well; then start with a signals and systems textbook. "Signals and Systems" by Oppenheim is a classic (and you get used books for (very) cheap), or you get the more modern "understanding digital signal processing" by Richard Lyons. You'll meet a lot of analysis and especially Fourier, Laplace transforms on the way –

Comment: very important to understand how the channel works – and you might want to find a math book that teaches you that. After you've gone through the signals and systems basics, there's some good communications engineering books; but MIT OpenCourseWare has "Principles of Digital Communications I", which has some overlap with the signals and systems books, and might be a good start.

Comment: Re: your first paragraph, I must be missing something, why do they need to be on the same line? Shouldn’t it rather be that the jammer and anti-jammer need to be the same distance from the receiver?

Comment: @jcaron a single jammer can only jam points that are at a fixed phase distance difference from both emitters (the hammer might adjust its phase such that it cancels exactly at the intentional emitter, and then any point behind it). Other loci would actually be hyperbolic, but I don't want to scare anyone with differential geometry